# PHP (If not existant in records.)

Tags: php, mysql

So basically I got this code right here:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig2.php';
$con = new DB_con();
$table = "users";
if(isset($_GET['profile_id']))
{
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_GET['profile_id']);
 $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
}
?>
```

I am clueless as to how I would make it so if the user_id is not existent in the records, they cannot view their profile but it leads them to another messsage or piece of code.

Comment: somethjing like `  if (mysql_num_rows($resullt)<1){die('INVALID USER');} `

Also, you really shouldn't be using PHPs MySQL function. Converting to MySQLI <note the letter i at the end.. is pretty easy and increases the security of your script. There are other options too, like PDO

Comment: 2005 called, they want their database API back! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: You should use prepared parameterized statements in order to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user_id doesn't exist, there won't be any rows in the result. When you try to read a row with `mysql_fetch_array()`, it returns `FALSE`. So you can simply test `$result`:

```
if (!$result) {
    die("Invalid profile ID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use prepared statements using mysqli, in order to avoid sql injection.

By way of example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "connect_error". $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$id = $_GET['profile_id'];
$result = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
$result->bind_param("i", $id);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($col1);
$result->fetch();
$is_valid_profile = (!$col1) ? 'Invalid profile' : 'Valid profile';
echo $is_valid_profile;
$result->close();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php